# How to Stream Udp multicast through live555 linux and then open up a rtsp network stream read by VLC

Tags: vlc, live555

I am trying to setup a network where I am reading a broadcast with live555 and then trying to send out an RTSP server I was reading the tutorials on the website and couldnt find what I was doing wrong.  My process was I opened up a streaming network through VLC to stream udp to the port that live555 was listening to then I opened testOnDemandRTSPServer for live555 and then opened a network stream from another VLC to listen to the rtsp stream but was getting no output does anyone know what I did wrong

Comment: I know you can stream from vlc to vlc but right now I am only using vlc for testing I am getting a stream from something else later

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem was that I was using a virtual machine and had bad network setting and had to disable something, I also changed the code in testOnDemandRTSPServer.cpp to line 340 and changed inputStreamIsRawUDP to True

Comment: When I change `inputStreamIsRawUDP to True` I get some errors reading with **ffplay** like: `[rtsp @ 0x7fe290009280] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
rtsp://192.168.120.208:8554/mpeg2TransportStreamFromUDPSourceTest: could not find codec parameters`

Comment: When I do that I get `Missing sync byte!` error. I doen't work. Any idea? Did you see with ffplay?